# Texturing two triangles (rectangle) with a depth texture gives all red colors

Tags: java, opengl, textures, shader, lwjgl

I am implementing shadow mapping in my program, and as intermediate step I want to be able to see the depth texture that has been generated after the first light pass, however all I see on the screen is red, relevant code:

```
@Override
protected void render(final double msDelta) {
    super.render(msDelta);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    //Light pass
    glViewport(0, 0, 4096, 4096);
    ...

    //Draw pass
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    ...

    //Visualize depth texture
    if (visualDepthTexture) {
        glViewport(100, screenHeight - (screenHeight / 5) - 100, screenWidth / 5, screenHeight / 5);
        glClearDepthf(1f);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        depthTexture.bind();
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
        depthBox.draw(0);
        depthTexture.unbind();
    }
}
```

where `depthTexture`:

```
    //shadow FBO and texture
    depthFBO = new FrameBufferObject().create().bind();
    depthTexture = new Texture2D().create().bind()
            .storage2D(11, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 4096, 4096)   //11 is log2(4096)
            .minFilter(GL_LINEAR)
            .magFilter(GL_LINEAR)
            .compareMode(GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE)
            .compareFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    depthFBO.texture2D(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0)
            .unbind();
    depthTexture.unbind();
```

And `depthBox.draw(0)` will draw 6 vertices in `GL_TRIANGLES` mode, using the following shaders:

`depth-box.vs.glsl`

```
#version 430 core

void main(void) {
    const vec4 vertices[6] = vec4[](
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),

        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    ); 

    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
}
```

`depth-box.fs.glsl`

```
#version 430 core

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D shadow_tex;

out vec4 color;

void main(void) {
    color = vec4(texture2D(shadow_tex, gl_FragCoord.xy));
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the depth texture gets converted to grayscale (to see where shadow should occur), and that the two triangles in the small viewport get textured with that result.

Comment: try using  `float z = vec4(texture2D(shadow_tex, gl_FragCoord.xy).r);` it will be mostly white(or black) because of the precision of the depth buffer, so you can use `pow(texture2D(...).r,SomeValue)` to see the actual depth better and `SomeValue` should be around ~16.0 if not try to play arrount with it.

Comment: @Raxvan Still all white, I know that in the other shaders I access the texture with `textureProj(shadow_tex, fs_in.shadow_coord)` to get back the `float` indicating the color (black if in shadow). However I'm still massively confused. What data is even in the depthbuffer, how is it being visualized with `color = textureProj(shadow_tex, fs_in.shadow_coord) * vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);`?

Comment: whell , first of all make sure you are actually rendering something in that buffer.Second, it could be the position in the vertex shader broken, try using `vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 0.5, 1.0)`(0.5 instead of 1.0). Third, could be all white even if you are rendering things in, it it's because the depth buffer has uneven precision meaning that for values from let's say 0.0 to 0.1 more bits are used than for values 0.1 to 1.0

Comment: @Raxvan I'm sorry, but what you are suggesting more sounds like hotfixes than an actual explanation of the problem. I agree that everyone is happy with working code, but I'd be able to make working code myself the next time.

Comment: yes, it can be a milion things that could go wrong there so that's why i'm not willing to post a 1000 lines of reply. If you can identify the problem from this then i can reply with a proper explanation.

Comment: @Raxvan There is, however, no problem with the problem formulation at all. I have a depth buffer that contains given data, and all I ask is how to visualize it. Maybe my current code does not even make sense, but that's what I have came up with so far.